# How to convert arrays from two different table columns to parallel rows?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm working with **hive** and I have a table of the following format (I present only one row, but it has many rows)

```
_______________________________
segments | rates     | sessID
---------|-----------|---------
'1,2,3'  | '10,20,30'| 555
```

Namely, two columns have a string representing arrays of the same length and the third column has some integer. I want to flatten the arrays such that first member of the first array appears in the same row with the first member of the second array, etc:
Something like:

```
----------------------------
segment | rate | sessId 
--------|------|------------
1       | 10   | 555
2       | 20   | 555
3       | 30   | 555
```

I've tried the following query (*for simplicity I've hardcoded the values*):

```
SELECT explode(segments), explode (rates), sessID FROM 
(SELECT Split('1,2,3', ',') as segments, Split('10,20,30', ',') as rates, 555 as sessID) data ;
```

However, this does produce the required result, returning an error:

**FAILED: SemanticException 1:26 Only a single expression in the SELECT clause is supported with UDTF's. Error encountered near token 'rates'**

When I try to flatten just one column it does work:
The query:

```
SELECT explode(segments) FROM (
SELECT Split('1,2,3', ',') as segments, Split('10,20,30', ',') as rates, 555 as sessID) data ;
```

the result:

```
1
2
3
```

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Will the segments always start from 1 and monotonically increase from there?  *(`1,2` or `1,2,3` or `1,2,3,4`, etc?  but never `2,3,4` or `3,2,1`?)*

Comment: In the absence of more information, this may guide you in the right direction: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65227/hive-explode-lateral-view-clarification.html

Comment: no, not sure the values increase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Hive to test this, but the approach ***should*** basically work.

`POSEXPLODE()` can be used to get two columns, the position within an array and the item itself.  Then you can use that position to look up the corresponding item from the other array...

```
SELECT
  yourData.sessID,
  segment.item                              AS segment,
  SPLIT(yourData.rates, ',')[segment.pos]   AS rate
FROM
  yourData
LATERAL VIEW
  POSEXPLODE(SPLIT(yourData.segments,',')) segment AS pos, item
```

I *think* that `POSEXPLODE()` returns the positions starting from `1`, but array indexes in Hive start from `0`?  If that's the case then use `[segment.pos - 1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try on this.

```
select sessID,tf1.val as segments, tf2.val as rates
  from (SELECT Split('1,2,3', ',') as segments, Split('10,20,30', ',') as rates, 555 as sessID) t
  lateral view posexplode(segments) tf1
  lateral view posexplode(rates) tf2
  where tf1.pos = tf2.pos;  

+---------+-----------+--------+--+
| sessid  | segments  | rates  |
+---------+-----------+--------+--+
| 555     | 1         | 10     |
| 555     | 2         | 20     |
| 555     | 3         | 30     |
+---------+-----------+--------+--+
```